# How do I capture all input names of $ _POST ['my_image']?

Tags: php

I have dynamic inputs with names `my_image[url]` and `my_image[caption]`

```
<input name="my_image[url]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $imgurl['url'];?>"/>
<input name="my_image[caption]" type="text" value="<?php echo $imgurl['caption'];?>">
```

Even inserting several images and captions dynamically, inside the isset the `$ _POST ['my_image']` is capturing only 1 image 1 caption:

```
if (isset($_POST['my_image'])){ 
    update_option('imagens_inicio',array($_POST['my_image']);
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST['my_image']);echo '</pre>';
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(96) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/4e07dd2bd752b989e9b4687129982977.jpg"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(0) "test text"
  }
}
```

How do I do in `isset` to capture all images and captions of `$_POST['my_image']`?

SOLVED:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$caption = $_POST['caption'];

$data = array_map(function ($url, $caption) {
        return compact('url', 'caption');
}, $url, $caption);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, only isset won't get you the result you need.

Since my_image[url] will always resolve to $_POST['my_image']['url'] it will indeed be overwritten. If you use [] php will automatically increase a number for every occurance, however in this case it will not put the url and the caption together.

If you want to be sure you receive the data in the way you provide you could name the input fields like this:

```
my_image[0][url]
my_image[0][caption]
my_image[1][url]
my_image[1][caption]
etc...
```

You could also reshape the data for example:

```
url[]
caption[]
url[]
caption[]
etc
```

Then you can use some processing to combine the data in php:

```
<?php
$data = array_map(function ($url, $caption) {
    return compact('url', 'caption');
}, $_POST['url'], $_POST['caption']);

var_dump($data);
```

To read the values:

```
foreach ($data as $image) {
    echo $image['caption'].': '.$image['url'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Ofcourse this needs to be wrapped in an isset && is_array check for the $_POST['url'] and $_POST['caption']

Comment: I read about the functions `array_map` and `compact`, thank you very much and now I understand your answer, but it is still returning null for `var_dump($data);`

Comment: `$_POST['url'];` and `$_POST['caption'];` directly in `array_map` was not working, now it's ok. Thanks a million